# How can we implement the exclusion function with using API

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

As we see, in SoftLayer's customer portal the exclusion of the specific configuration is automatically detected.
For example, we cannot select VSI's 25 GB First Disk with Windows OS before verifying the order.
I know we have verifyOrder method for Product_Order service but it require us to provide all the configuration at least.
Do we have any other way to detect the invalid configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is updated according the conflicts between items, to get that information you should use the following method:

- [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemConflicts](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemConflicts)

Also another method that can help, due to sometimes there are conflict between item and location:

- [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemLocationConflicts](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemLocationConflicts)

You can try the following script that I created, it will provide enough information from a specific package: the available locations, the location conflicts for items and the conflicts between items

```
"""
Get item prices information

This script retrieves information of prices from a package. It retrieves the item description,
location conflicts, pricing location group and item conflicts

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getRegions
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

@License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
@Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer
from prettytable import PrettyTable
# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
# Declare the image template id
packageId = 46
# Create a client instance
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
# Declare an object mask to get location conflicts
objectMask = 'mask[pricingLocationGroup[locations],item[locationConflicts, conflicts]]'

try:
    locations = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getRegions(id=packageId)
    items = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItems(id=packageId)
    print('*****  AVAILABLE LOCATIONS  *****')
    for location in locations:
        print('Id: %s,  Location: %s' % (location['location']['location']['id'], location['location']['location']['longName']))
    itemPrices = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItemPrices(id=packageId, mask=objectMask)
    items = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItems(id=packageId, mask='mask[prices]')
    x = PrettyTable(["Price Id", "Item Id", "Description", "Datacenter conflicts", "Pricing Location", 'Price conflicts', 'Item conflicts'])
    x.align["Price Id"] = "l"  # Left align city names
    x.padding_width = 1
    for price in itemPrices:
        dcConflicts = ''
        pricingLocation = ''
        conflictItems = ''
        conflictPrices = ''
        # Get location conflicts
        if  len(price['item']['locationConflicts']) > 0:
            for locationConflicts in price['item']['locationConflicts']:
                for location in locations:
                    if locationConflicts['resourceTableId'] == location['location']['location']['id']:
                        dcConflicts = dcConflicts + ' ' + location['location']['location']['longName']
        else:
            dcConflicts = "None"
        # Get Pricing location
        if 'pricingLocationGroup' in price:
            for priceLocation in price['pricingLocationGroup']['locations']:
                pricingLocation = pricingLocation + ' ' + priceLocation['longName']
        else:
            pricingLocation = 'Standard price'
        # Get item conflicts
        if len(price['item']['conflicts']) > 0:
            for conflict in price['item']['conflicts']:
                for item in items:
                    if conflict['resourceTableId'] == item['id']:
                        conflictItems = conflictItems + ' ' + str(conflict['resourceTableId'])
                        for priceConf in item['prices']:
                            conflictPrices = conflictPrices + ' ' + str(priceConf['id'])
        if conflictItems == '':
            conflictItems = 'None'
            conflictPrices = 'None'
        x.add_row([price['id'], price['item']['id'], price['item']['description'], dcConflicts, pricingLocation, conflictPrices, conflictItems])
    print(x)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get item prices faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

I hope it helps, let me know if you have any doubt or comment