# How to get the list of items, their categories and their prices with valid items only?

Tags: c#, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the following REST API call to get the list of items available for ordering an hourly Virtual server:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/46.json?objectMask=configuration;configuration.itemCategory;itemPrices;itemPrices.item;itemPrices.categories;itemPrices.item.softwareDescription
```

The problem I am having is that this call returns a very large number of items and hence is making the call slow.

Is there any way to modify the call such that it only returns valid items (i.e., only those items that are displayed on the order page on control.softlayer.com) e.g., on control.softlayer.com, while ordering an hourly virtual server, the list of operating systems does not include Windows Server 2008, however the results from the above call includes windows Server 2008. Similarly, there are several such items that are not displayed while ordering from the softlayer portal but are returned in the above call.

Comment: The URL you provided does not work for us since we need username and password to access it. There is no way of telling whether it is possible without knowing the API - as long as its developers provide a way to do it it is possible, otherwise, not.

Answer (score 0):

The portal perform several requests to filter the data and only displays the valid information for that it uses the methods:

[SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemConflicts](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemConflicts)
[SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemLocationConflicts](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemLocationConflicts)

if you want to get the same information as the portal you need to apply those filters:

here an example about that using python:

[How can we implement the exclusion function with using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983252/how-can-we-implement-the-exclusion-function-with-using-api)

however the portal do more filters, for some items, based on the attributes of each item, so it is not easy to get the same result as the portal keep that in mind.

Regards